# cordova/phonegap 3.3: how to set user credentials in fileUploadOptions

Tags: authentication, file-upload, cordova

I'm trying to make a file upload via Phonegap 3.3 file transfer plugin to a windows server secured by base authentication. Actually the normal conversation between my app and the server (per ajax) is working perfectly by sending my user credentials with every ajax call.

```
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
    options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
    options.chunkedMode = false;
    options.headers = {
        'Authorization':authHeaderValue(db.getItem("user"), db.getItem("pass")) 
    };
```

and

```
authHeaderValue = function(username, password) {
    var tok = username + ':' + password;
    var hash = btoa(tok);
    return "Basic " + hash;
};
```

This is what I tried so far (I found it on stackoverflow thread) but it gives me back a 401-unauthorized...

Pls. give me a short reply if you know something that could help me.

Best regards to you all,

Ingmar

Comment: Make use of fiddler to intercept the ajax request to get noe the exact syntax for sending credentials

Answer (score 0):

Well, I do something similar but instead of "Basic" I use JWT for authentication. I'll show you the code I use:

```
options.headers = { 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + app.session.getSess('token') };
```

And I use SessionStorage to save the token while it is valid.
If you wanna know about [JSON Web Token](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/07/angularjs-authentication-with-cookies-vs-token/)

Another thing, remember to change the headers in your server, in my case something like:

```
('Access-Control-Allow-Origin','*');
('Access-Control-Allow-Methods','GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
('Access-Control-Allow-Headers','Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');
```